# Ruby on Rails, how to stop navbar rendering on Log-In page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, partials

In my application a user is taken straight to log-in before they can enter the main site.

I am rendering a navbar partial across the site but I don't want the navbar rendered on the log-in page. I don't want to have to copy and paste the navbar code in to all the views in order to prevent this.

It would be cleaner if there was a way I could stop the navbar showing on the login screen without having to remove the partial.

How do you restrict a partial view from one page in your application?

I am using Devise.

I don't think code is needed in this post but happy to provide if helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Devise and you are in a login page, then there is no logged user. Then you may use one of the Devise helpers to achieve what you want. Something like:

```
if (not user_signed_in?) then
    render 'your_partial_with_the_navbar'
end
```

The only point here is the fact the partial wouldn't render in any page where there is no user logged.

You could also create a better helper yourself, combining the **user_signed_in?** from Devise with other conditions of yours.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I did the following in the applications layout file <% if (user_signed_in?) then %>
    <div id="navbar"><%= render 'shared/navbar'%></div>
<% end %>  This works fine. All users have to be logged in anyway so it should be ok. Thanks again.

Comment: Good that it helped. And thanks for accepting the answer.